# SSN format in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I could use some help creating an XSL template that will take a string of numbers (i.e., 123456789) and format that string into a Social Security Number format (i.e., 123-45-6789).  I found [one example](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/199905/post00480.html) on the Internet, but it seemed overcomplicated.

I'm new to XSLT, so please keep that in mind when replying.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT 1.0's string functions are a bit limited, but fortunately this isn't too hard:

Assuming < ssn >123456789< /ssn>:

```
<xsl:template match="ssn">    
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 0, 4)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 4, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 6, 4)"/>    
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2.0, concat() can take more than two arguments, so it's a single line:

```
  <xsl:template match="ssn">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 0, 4), '-', substring(., 4, 2), '-', substring(., 6, 4))" />    
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you could also nest concat()s:
    <xsl:template match="ssn">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 0, 4), concat('-', concat(substring(., 4, 2), concat('-', substring(., 6,4)))))"/>
    </xsl:template>
But your option is much more readable :)